# Segfaulting on function call (C)

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, segmentation-fault

So, I'm at somewhat of a loss right now and hoping someone can help.  I have a function defined in a library called 'list_free' which, as you can imagine, frees a list that you created earlier.  When I call this function from within another module, my program segfaults.  When running GDB though, I get:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  *__GI___libc_free (mem=0x65656853) at malloc.c:3709
#1  0x0804f279 in list_free ()
#2  0x0012ffef in set_var (...) at src/calc/model.c:337
#3  0x0804b320 in test_dependency_updates (_i=0) at src/tests/test_calc.c:63
#4  0x080507ea in srunner_run_all ()
#5  0x0804d2b9 in main () at src/tests/test_all.c:19
```

Thus, the line that caught my attention was #1 ... there is no reference to the source of that function.  When I change the name of the function from `list_free` to `list_freex` (i.e., just something different) no more segfault.  The other strange thing is if I change the name in the .c file, I get no warning of an "undefined reference to list_free" or whatever error I would get from forgetting to link in a library.

Thus, I'm led to believe that the function is being defined elsewhere, but I have no idea where.  A `grep -R list_free .` offers no help and the gdb output doesn't seem to indicate otherwise.

So I'm wondering if anyone has any tips on how to hunt down where this function might be defined.  Also, I've renamed the function as noted above for now as I don't seem to have any other choice ... but I'm not sure if this is a good/safe idea?  Ie, could I just be masking other problems by doing so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At least supply excerpts from test_calc.c, model.c plus related header files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try producing a link map from the linker.

On my system, to produce a map on stdout (lots and lots of lines)

```
    gcc ... -Wl,-M ...
    ###       ^ lowercase L
```

Or, to create a file with the map

```
    gcc ... -Wl,-Map,a.map ...
```

Comment: Ah!!  Amazing ... thanks for the suggestion.  I used `-Wl,-Map,out.map` so that I could view it in a file (was having problems looking at it from the command line) ... found out it was linking to a function of the same name in another library (check unit testing library)!  So was wondering - do you know how I can tell GCC to utilize my 'list_free' function rather than check's?  Thanks again!

Comment: I think the order you specify the libraries on the command line matters. Try switching the order they appear in

Comment: Indeed... it just picks the first one found in the order they appear in the command line. I expected gcc saying `multiple definition of ...`. Is there any way to find nasty bugs like that without manually checking map files?

Comment: This is a linker issue, not the compiler (the compiler would have complained with the `multiple definition` message). I couldn't find a way to make the linker complain ...

Comment: Got it - I'll have to fiddle with it.  I'm using an automated build system so I'm not sure how I'll change this, but it makes sense.  Thanks again so much for your help!

Comment: @pmg: false, the linker does the same if you have multiple definitions in separate object files...

Comment: @yi_H: I think we're saying the same thing in different words. The linker complains when given two object files (.o) with two functions with the same name; it doesn't complain when given two libraries (.a or .so) containing object files with functions with the same name (or even one library with two objects ...)

Comment: I did a [play session with several compilation options](http://p20110627.pastebin.fr/11786) to try and find out what happens on my system :)

Answer (score 7):

If you are using linux, `valgrind` is an invaluable tool to find problems with your memory management.

Comment: Thanks - should have mentioned that too.  I did use valgrind and it was telling me that there was an invalid read.  But I couldn't figure out how that was possible?  Ie, I tried to debug where an invalid read occurred but couldn't find one ... and wouldn't I still be getting a segfault / invalid read after I changed the function name?  That is, I no longer get an invalid read after changing the function name?

Comment: Yes, I do compile with -Wall.